# D mixin with factory

Tags: factory, mixins, d

Consider I have the following classes:

```
/// File classes.d
class C {
    string type() { return "C"; };
}

class C1 : C {
    override string type() { return "C1"; };
}

class C2 : C {
    override string type() { return "C1"; };
}
```

Now I want to implement a factory somewhere else, like:

```
/// File factory.d
module factory;
import std.functional;
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    mixin(import("classes.d"));
    auto c = cast(typeof(mixin("C1"))) Object.factory("C1");
    writeln(c.type());
}
```

The compiler (dmd 2.058) says me:

```
factory.d(7): Error argument C1 to typeof is not an expression
```

I know the following line compiles well:

```
auto c = cast(C1) Object.factory("classes.C1");
```

but this requires me to know the type (C1) at compile time. I want to get the type at runtime (like a string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mixin(`auto c = cast(typeof(C1)) Object.factory("C1");`)
```

I don't understand you question, I think:
You want to cast dynamically at runtime to a given type? This is not possible in a statically typed language! What you can do is, passing your classes (or whatever) around as `void*` and using a switch … case to cast it to the needed type (you can also use [`std.variant`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html), which is maybe the better way, but I've never used it) and then calling different functions (templated functions):

```
final switch(which_type) {
    case "C1": foo(cast(C1)bar); break;
    case "C2": foo(cast(C2)bar); break;
}

void foo(T)(T a) {
}
```

You can also generate the switch case at compile-time:

```
final switch(which_type) {
    foreach(i; TypeTuple("C1", "C2")) {
        case i: foo(mixin(`cast(` ~ i ~ `)bar`); break;
    }
}
```

If you just wanna get the string of the type `typeof(bar).stringof` will give you the type of `bar` as string (but this is already known at compile time).

Answer (score 5):

Mixins are a compile time artifact and can only be used at compile time. `typeof` can only be used at compile time. D is a statically typed language, and all types must be known at compile time.

You can have a reference of a base class type which refers to a derived class instance, so something like this is possible:

```
C makeC(string type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case "C": return new C;
        case "C1": return new C1;
        case "C2": return new C2;
        default: throw new Exception(format("%s is not a C", tye));
    }
}

C c = makeC("C1");
```

There's also [`std.variant`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html) which can be used  to hold different types (it uses a union internally).

But you can't decide what the type of a variable is going to be at runtime, because D is statically typed.